# FatalThrowableError in User.php line 7: Class 'App\Authenticatable' not found (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I have used this code
User.php file

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;
        protected $guarded = ['role'];
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];
    }
?>
```

> Error:  FatalThrowableError in User.php line 7: Class
>   'App\Authenticatable' not found

How can I solve it?

Comment: Appropriate documentation: [Autoload in PHP](http://php.net/autoload), [PSR guidelines](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $guarded = ['role'];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in User.php line 8:
Class App\User cannot extend from trait Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable

Comment: It doesn't work !!
FatalErrorException in User.php line 8:
Class App\User cannot extend from trait Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable

Comment: FatalThrowableError in UsersController.php line 25:
Call to undefined method App\User::create()

Answer (score 0):

The class that Laravel uses is `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` which they alias as `Authenticatable`.

At the top of your user model, you can import this base class which the default User model extends:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

This base class implements the standard interfaces and uses the standard traits (including the one named Authenticatable) for you.

Comment: FatalErrorException in User.php line 10:
App\User cannot use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User - it is not a trait

Comment: @AminAtaee, yes because this is not a trait. So if it is a class you inherit from it using `extends` when it is trait like `Notifiable` you are using `use` to include it in the class.

Comment: @nakov Thank you !

Comment: @AminAtaee you should read http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php so you understand the difference between importing a class and using a trait.